# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ΓÇôi'

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to add watermark png to multiple videos using subprocess.Popen() but the code results in error

```
import os

def runBash(command):
   os.system(command)

inpu="1.mp4"
png="crop.png"
str="ffmpeg –i "+inpu+" -vf "+ "\"movie="+png+" [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]\" "+"eargaergaerg"+inpu
runBash(str) 
print(str)
```

Error

```
error: [NULL @ 000002210b65af40] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ΓÇôi'
ΓÇôi: Invalid argument
```

Comment: which line makes problem? Always show this line in question.

Comment: did you try string from `str` copy and use manually in console/terminal ?

Comment: if i try manually to copy paste ffmpeg code directly in cmd  it works ! but throws only given error in cmd terminal when executed from python script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
The problem was caused by using a long dash –i instead of -i

When I run your exact python code it works. It seems like there is an incorrectly encoded or escaped character in your command so maybe try saving the code with utf-8 codec in your text editor.

Comment: i m using python 3.7 its by default utf-8

Comment: Found the problem. You used the long dash for –i instead of a normal dash -i.

Comment: it worked ! i would i have never figured it out such a small thing ! thanks a ton @dj_rydu but it endded up in other error :[NULL @ 00000224ae93fb00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[watermark];'
[watermark];: Invalid argument

Comment: Could you please accept my answer since it solved the problem that you posted? As to your new problem I have no idea how to reproduce it. For me everything works. Are you sure all the characters are correct now?

Comment: with changes u mentioned i manually copy pasted str in cmd it worked ! but same str if i run it from jupyter it produces mentioned error any way thanks man i have accepted ur answer cheers!